# Angular2 InputFormControl and ValueChange fires continuously

Tags: angular, service, rxjs, valuechangelistener

I have a simple case where input is detected from an input field. when the value changes on the input, and after a short debounce time, a service is called which makes a http call and some data is returned.

However, instead of only firing once or twice, the service is calling the api between 16-30 times - even if the input is only 4 characters and therefore should fire 4 times.

My suspicioun is this may be to do with callbacks, or that I am implementing the valueChanges method incorrectly. In any case i have attached some code for review and would appreciate any feedback any input as I am new to angular and cannot see any error in implementation.

```
inputChange(input) {
    this.inputFormControl.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(5000)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap(input => this.userService.search(input))
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data;
        },
    );
}
```

Comment: If you can put together a Plunker or StackBlitz, that'd be awesome

Comment: Not enough context... like @ChauTran said give us a stackblitz or something so we can help.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling a method `inputChange(input)` when the value changes (assumingly) and your are **also** subscribing to `valueChanges`. Drop the `inputChange` method, and just use `valueChanges`:

```
constructor() {
  this.inputFormControl.valueChanges
    .debounceTime(5000)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .switchMap(input => this.userService.search(input))
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
    }); 
}
```

Also remember to unsubscribe when component is destroyed!